# What does this notice in PHP mean?

Tags: php

I've been doing a lot of work with sockets and PHP on my localhost server (XAMPP) and I get this notice often:

[image]

This is line 88 and it's surrounding code:

```
public function ph_write($ph_data) {

    //Write the data to the socket.
    LINE 88-> return fwrite($this->socket,$ph_data);

}
```

How can I prevent this from happening? It sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_299.asp That is Error 10053

Comment: @Webice Pretty ambiguous error...

Comment: @Webice If you don't mind, could you explain it in even simpler terms? I'm still fairly new to this stuff.

Comment: @user3681788 I'am sorry. Didn't get this error right now. Only knows the other Topics around here. Maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923815/fsockopen-10053-error-when-writing-chars-to-java-socket